# Extract Number before a Character in a String Using Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to extract the number before character "M" in a series of strings. The strings may look like:

```
"107S33M15H"
"33M100S"
"12M100H33M"
```

so basically there would be a sets of numbers separated by different characters, and "M" may show up more than once. For the example here, I would like my code to return:

```
33
33
12,33 #doesn't matter what deliminator to use here
```

One way I could think of is to split the string by "M", and find items that are pure numbers, but I suspect there are better ways to do it. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may use a simple `(\d+)M` regex (*1+ digit(s) followed with `M`* where the digits are captured into a capture group) with `re.findall`.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/DTDsPw):

```
import re
s = "107S33M15H\n33M100S\n12M100H33M"
print(re.findall(r"(\d+)M", s))
```

And here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vY9eY5/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use rpartition to achieve that job.

```
s = '107S33M15H'    
prefix = s.rpartition('M')[0]
```

Comment: I used this to add a new column to my data frame. This is the code:  df['new_col'] = df.old_col.str.rpartition('b')[2]  # Where b is the letter to be removed and 2 is the position in the 'rpartition' array of the characters you want in the new column. Thanks for the code. was very useful.