# Match all digits up to and after a specific character excluding character

Tags: python, mysql, regex, sqlalchemy

I'm building two hybrid expressions in SQL Alchemy where I want to select i) all the digits before and ii) all the digits after a hyphen in a string.

Given the string `6-12(1)` I'd like the outputs `6` and `12` respectively.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36167504/11277108) answer I figured I'd need `r"(\d+)-"` for i) so:

```
@digits_before.expression
def digits_before(cls):
    return func.regexp_substr(cls.string_field, r"(\d+)-")
```

However, this returns `6-` for the record in question.

Looking at the SQL that's generated the regex string is reduced to `'(d+)-'` - could this be why?

What are the correct two regex strings I need to use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the backslash is removed, you need to double it in the code. Better, just use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

Comment: Thanks. So changed the Python regex to `r"([0-9]+)-"` which produced `"([0-9]+)-"` in SQL however I'm still getting `"6-"` :-(

Comment: Correct, `regexp_substr` only returns the first match and returns the whole match, not just the captured part unless you specify the group ID as the third argument.

Comment: Ah ok. When I read through the documentation the third argument is `pos` which is the position in the string to start the search - pretty sure this isn't what I want? The fourth and final argument is `occurence` - is this the group ID you mean? I'm not sure what to enter here?

Comment: Ok, if there is no group number to pass, it does not even allow that (it does in some other implementations).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this regexp would capture the two numbers:

```
(\d+)-(\d+)
```

This gets just the first number, but verifies that there is a second:

```
(\d+)-\d+
```

Vice versa:

```
\d+-(\d+)
```

Comment: Thanks Rick - I was actually looking to build two hybrid expressions rather than get both of the numbers together.

Comment: @Jossy - I added some stuff; Is that what you mean?