# Which methods can I use to extract the coefficients of a letter from a string in python?

Tags: python

I want to extract the coefficients of x from a string inputted into my program

```
equation = input("Type in your equation")
# inputted string: "5x + 10x + 15x + 30"

var_data = []

def varr(equation):   
    var = input("What variable are you using?")  
    for i, ch in enumerate(equation):
        if ch == var:
            var_data.append(i)
           
    return var_data
```

I tried making the index list of the occurrences of x, but I didn't know how to get the numbers before those indexes/indices. I thought about reverse slicing but not sure if it may work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract Number before a Character in a String Using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167442/extract-number-before-a-character-in-a-string-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this using regular expressions:

```
import re

var = input("What variable are you using?")  
result =  list(re.findall(r'\d+', var))
result = [int(i) for i in result]
```

At this point your resulting list `result` should have all the coefficients of your equation so you have to just iterate over them and sum them up. This under assumption that you enter properly formatted string of your equation.
Notice that you can take `result[:-1]` part to get rid of the last element or skip it.

Comment: When I tried it 30 still showed even though it's not a coefficient of x

Comment: Just do ```result = result[:-1]``` to skip the last value.

Comment: That works but what if is in a different format like 10x +  5 + 15x

Comment: That's beyond what was initially. You can experiment - I showed you how to manipulate the list, so you can branch into other conditions. You can handle edge cases based out of what I provided.

Comment: `var` is the variable in the equation (`'x'`), not the equation itself. You've got the right idea of using regex, you just need to include `var` in the regex so it only matches the coefficients of the powers of `var`

Comment: Do you know how to do that?